# C conditional increment

Tags: c, conditional-statements, increment, temporary

Consider the following code:
int a=0 , b=1
If (a == --b)
    Printf b

Is b now 0 or 1?
In other words- is the increment temporary or not?

Thank you!

Comment: Make your program syntactically correct, then try it. (`If`? `Printf b`? Really?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, `b=0` now. And the decrement is permanent within the scope of the function you have defined `b` in.

Comment: Thank you! How can I go around it and not modify b (without using another var)?

Comment: Simply write `if(a==b-1)` instead of `if(a==--b)`

Answer (score 1):

Its a decrement and yes it will modify `b`.

Comment: 1. This doesn't answer the question! The question is: *Is b now 0 or 1* 2. It also depends if it is prefix or postfix! 3. With answering questions with no effort you are supporting this behavior

Comment: @Rizier123; It answers the question.

Comment: How? *Is b now 0 or 1?* <- Still an open question. Also saw point 2 and 3 of my last comment?

Comment: @Rizier123; *it will modify `b`*: What does that mean?

Comment: *In other words- is the increment temporary or not?* Seems like OP doesn't know that it's decrement, so how should he know what it does? and *modify* could mean anything! And still be aware of point 2 and 3 of my first comment

Comment: @Rizier123; Did I said in my answer that its a decrement?

Comment: Sorry, didn't edit it correctly, it's of course decrement, no need to get so excited.

Answer (score 1):

Initially b is assigned a value 1. When you use  --b (pre decrement),it first decrement the value of b to 0  and then compute the condition ,which is true.